# removing redundant data

Tags: bash, shell

I have a file which looks like this (3 columns and n number of rows)

```
chr8    101999980   102031975
chr8    101999980   102033533 
chr8    101999980   102033533 
chr8    101999980   102032736 
chr8    101999980   102034799 
chr8    101999980   102034799 
chr8    101999980   102034397
chr8    101999980   102032736
```

and from this data I want to remove the redundant lines and these exact repeated data could be present anywhere in this dataset with a bash script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
sort yourfile | uniq > outputfile
```

If order does not matter.

It works on adjacent identical rows, that's why you need sort. In your file, you don't need sort because the duplicates come right next to each other. If that is not the standard case, you need to sort the file first.

```
$ uniq yourfile | wc -l
6
$ sort yourfile | uniq | wc -l
6
```

With and without sort both return 6 lines, but you did not say it is the default.

Comment: are u sure, I think uniq will work on any one column and not on matching all three columns.

Comment: It works on adjacent identical rows, that's why you need sort. In your file, you don't need sort because the duplicates come right next to each other. If that would not be the standard case, you need to sort the file first.

Answer (score 4):

If maintaining the order is important:

```
awk '!c[$0]++' filename
```

This can be read as follows:

- pushes each line as an array key (`c[$0]`),
- post-increments (`++`) the value to keep a count of such lines, and
- performs the default action only if the line has never been seen before (`!`)

  - `n++` returns 0, or false, if n is unset
  - the default action is `{print}`

Comment: That's *quite* cool. A link to the relevant section of the docs would be awesome, too :)

Answer (score 3):

You can pipe your file through [sort](http://linux.die.net/man/1/sort) and [uniq](http://linux.die.net/man/1/uniq):

```
$ sort yourFile | uniq > newFile
```

Comment: are u sure, I think uniq will work on any one column and not on matching all three columns.

Comment: @Angelo, nope, `uniq` will check the whole lines. You'd need to introduce something like `cut` in the pipeline in order to filter on only one column.